# 'anyway' or 'either way' usage

Tags: informal-language

Is there any grammatical difference between 'anyway' and 'either way'?

I have posted an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888405/why-does-my-cron-job-run-every-1-minute-although-i-set-it-every-1-hour/888408#888408) but which one is correct?

> You can do in **anyway** or
>
> You can do in **either way**

Or both are correct in this case?
Which one, when should I use?

Comment: "do in" or "do it"?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Do you mean 'You can do it anyway' or 'You can do in anyway'?

Comment: Both of your examples have "do in" where "do it" would seem more natural.

Answer (score 1):

that's three questions in one. Regarding meaning, check the dictionary definition, because that's most of what you could expect of an answer here.

The usage of "any way" in your linked answer implies to me arbitrary ways, quite contrary to what you might mean. I'd say "either of these ways" although that precludes other possible ways, or I would leave the appendage out: "**you can do ... either: ... or:**"

Answer (score 1):

Anyway has a lot of uses

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/anyway

But the basic meaning is `regardless`

Either way means `in one of those two ways`